# Point ImageMagick at file format to use

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I wonder if it's not possible to give ImageMagick a hint what type the input string (or file) is.

E. g. treat `.sql` as textfile.

I would need it to be used in php (Imagick).

The only thing I get is an exception that the file format is unknown:

```
no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361
```

Comment: You could try leaving off the file extension and see what happens.

Comment: Huh? What is in `XYZ.sql` Please show the first few lines.

Comment: @Bonzo ImageMagick sticks on file extension. Without it I get errors for all files (supported too).

Comment: @MarkSetchell .sql is a database file - basically a text file with the database contents and build instructions.

Comment: @Bonzo Thank you, but what is **ImageMagick** going to do with a file that contains `CREATE TABLE fred (int age PRIMARY KEY)...`

Comment: You can tell **ImageMagick** that file `stuff.sql` is text by saying `TXT:stuff.sql` but I fail to see what you think it will do with a bunch of SQL commands?

Comment: @MarkSetchell ImageMagick is able to build screenshots from text(files) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell **ImageMagick** that a file contains text like this:

```
convert TEXT:stuff.sql result.png
```

which will give you an image of the contents of the text file `stuff.sql`.

So, if you want an image of a directory listing, you can do:

```
ls -l | convert TEXT:- listing.png
```

Or, if you have some SQL in a file `commands.sql`:

```
convert -background yellow -fill magenta text:commands.sql -trim result.png
```

[image]

Or, if you want it centred and with a larger border:

```
convert -background yellow -fill magenta text:commands.sql -trim  \
        -gravity center -extent 120%x120% result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @MarkSetchell mentioned you can tell ImageMagick the (custom) filetype by prefixing it.

```
FILETYPE:FILEPATH
```

eg

```
TXT:/path/to/file.sql
```

- I suppose you have to prefix a file format from specific list; `identify -list format` should give you that list of supported formats on linux
- This works also with php: `$im = new Imagick("txt:/path/to/file.sql");`
- Maybe someone knows how/if it works when having file contents as blob (`$im->readImageBlob(...)`)

Comment: You need to differentiate between `TXT:` and `TEXT:`. The former describes the coordinates and values inside an image whereas the latter means it is textual data and is what you want. If you want to see an example of the former, use `convert rose: txt:-` You want the latter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell While I can reproduce it on command line, it seems to make no difference when used with php's Imagick constructor. But maybe you can explain which prefixes are valid when it does not go with the extension. Is there any list (anywhere)? thx

Comment: I don't use the PHP interface much, but try `$image->setFormat('TEXT');`